# Converting symbols from outside of alphabet caused by copying text in different encoding

Tags: sql, oracle

In my database I should only have data written using Polish alphabet but sometimes there are symbols not included in Polish alphabet (words copied from source with different encoding) that correspond to Polish letters in another encoding. Is it possible to somehow convert symbols outside of Polish alphabet to corresponding letters?
The only solution I figured is to manually find and replace those characters but maybe you have better solution to my problem.

Question concerns Oracle SQL Language.

I don't have database in front of me but as I remember correctly the example could look like this - two rows from my db:

ŚWIAT

ÚWIAT

and what I need is to convert Ú that doesn't belong to Polish alphabet to Ś.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Experiment with it first to see if it works.

If I want to change every occurrence of the letter z with a j in a string, I would use the translate function:  `translate(text_string, 'z', 'j')`. I don't have to use the letters z and j; instead, I can write `translate(text_string, chr(122), chr(106)` - to find out the character code, I use `select ascii('z') from dual;`.  For example:

```
SQL> select translate('banzo', chr(122), chr(106)) from dual;

TRANS
-----
banjo
```

This changes every occurrence of z to j in text_string.

Now, you will have to find the code for the characters you want to change (both the "from" and the "to" characters) in your character set - it should be your session character set, not the database character set. (At least I think this is correct; experiment with it or read the documentation for CHR and perhaps for TRANSLATE - CHR returns the character code in the DATABASE character set unless you indicate otherwise, while I believe TRANSLATE uses the session character set.)

The function `ascii` may or may not work for non-ASCII characters, but if you google the name of your character set, you should find a character set table that will show you the codes for all the letters available in that character set.

Then, if this works, you can do the translation in one shot - `translate(text_string, 'abcd', 'qrst')` will change every 'a' to a 'q', every 'b' to an 'r' etc. And with `chr(...)`, instead of `'abcd'` you can write `chr(97) || chr(98) || chr(99) || chr(100)`.